# How to run jmeter http request sampler sequentially?

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I am aware of how to run jmeter thread groups sequentially, but i want to know that how to run the http request sampler in a thread group sequentially.

My samplers are 
1)start
2)in progress
3)resolved
4)end
If i set the thread as 1 and start the test
It is running sequentially, whereas if the no.of thread is more than 1 , it runs randomly like 1-3-2-4

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the JMeter [samplers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#samplers) run in the sequential order and when you add more than 1 user in the test run even then the samplers run in sequential order but though the users could be at different steps at a time thats why you are seeing that they are running in random order [1-3-2-4].

If your requirement is to run all the steps at the same time by all users then you can use Synchronizing Timer element which can wait for all the users to complete the current sampler request before proceeding to the next request.

You can refer to below blog posts of JMeter in order to get the thorough knowledge of JMeter elements: https://www.redline13.com/blog/kb/

Answer (score 1):

Add [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) under each HTTP Request and put the number of threads as `Number of Simultaneous Users to Group by`

> Number of Simultaneous Users to Group by
>   Number of threads to release at once. Setting it to 0 is equivalent to setting it to Number of threads in Thread Group.